# Combining multiple json and displaying it in Angular UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

i am trying to get json from multiple source and want to display it in the single Angular UI grid. in all these source first field is common .

Data format :

**Source :1**

```
var one=[ 
      { col1: "Heading 1", col2: "First 12", col3: "First 13"},
      { col1: "Heading 2", col2: "First 22", col3: "First 23"},
      { col1: "Heading 3", col2: "First 32", col3: "First 33"},
      { col1: "Heading 4", col2: "First 42", col3: "First 43"},
      { col1: "Heading 5", col2: "First 52", col3: "First 53"}
    ];
```

**Source: 2**

```
var two=[
      { col1: "Heading 1", col2: "Second 12", col3: "Second 13"},
      { col1: "Heading 2", col2: "Second 22", col3: "Second 23"},
      { col1: "Heading 3", col2: "Second 32", col3: "Second 33"},
      { col1: "Heading 4", col2: "Second 42", col3: "Second 43"},
      { col1: "Heading 5", col2: "Second 52", col3: "Second 53"}
    ];
```

I want it to be displayed in gird like this

[image]

Source:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants) {

var one=[ 
      { col1: "Heading 1", col2: "First 12", col3: "First 13"},
      { col1: "Heading 2", col2: "First 22", col3: "First 23"},
      { col1: "Heading 3", col2: "First 32", col3: "First 33"},
      { col1: "Heading 4", col2: "First 42", col3: "First 43"},
      { col1: "Heading 5", col2: "First 52", col3: "First 53"}
    ]; 1
     1
var two=[
      { col1: "Heading 1", col2: "Second 12", col3: "Second 13"},
      { col1: "Heading 2", col2: "Second 22", col3: "Second 23"},
      { col1: "Heading 3", col2: "Second 32", col3: "Second 33"},
      { col1: "Heading 4", col2: "Second 42", col3: "Second 43"},
      { col1: "Heading 5", col2: "Second 52", col3: "Second 53"}
    ];

  var finalObj = {

    "firstData":one,
    "secondData":two
  }


  console.log("finalObj"+JSON.stringify(finalObj));


  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'firstData.col1', displayName: 'Column 1', width: 175},
      {field: 'firstData.col2', displayName: 'Column 2', width: '*'},
      {field: 'firstData.col3', displayName: 'Column 3', width: 120},
      {field: 'secondData.col2', displayName: 'Column 4', width: '*'},
      {field: 'secondData.col3', displayName: 'Column 5', width: 120}
    ],
    enableRowSelection: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
    };
  $scope.gridOptions=finalObj;

}]);
```

Code : see the attaced Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUyJQInnygirvfohIhQo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `$scope.gridOptions=finalObj;` needs to be changed to `$scope.gridOptions.data=finalObj;`

2) `$scope.gridOptions.data` needs an `array`.

Try this:

```
function merge(obj1, obj2){
    return obj1.map(function(o1){
      return Object.assign({}, o1, {
        col4: obj2.find(function(o2){ return o1.col1 == o2.col1 }).col2,
        col5: obj2.find(function(o2){ return o1.col1 == o2.col1 }).col3
      })
    })
}

var finalObj = merge(one, two);

$scope.gridOptions.data=finalObj;
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2jKhbURFMtXHxIaFou2?p=preview)